# error with Google+ button Badge

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-plus

I want to use this button on my page but when I use chrome script appears to create a new circle, the same happens in firefox and safari explorer only works on analyzing with the console I get this error

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)** /+1/fastbutton?bsv&annotation=inline&width=300&hl=en-US&origin=file%3A%2F%2F&url=file%3A%2F%2F%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fusuario%2FDesktop%2Fnoche.html&jsh=m%3B%2F%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fgapi%2F_*features*_%2Frt%3Dj%2Fver%3DlgJnpFHo_sE.es.%2Fsv%3D1%2Fam%3D!9YrXPIrxx2-ITyEIjA%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTMUGsaYaMyYb_qFDQo8MG8RKB82aQ#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Conload&id=I1_1352910400423&parent=file%3A%2F%2F">https://plusone.google.com/*/+1/fastbutton?bsv&annotation=inline&width=300&hl=en-US&origin=file%3A%2F%2F&url=file%3A%2F%2F%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fusuario%2FDesktop%2Fnoche.html&jsh=m%3B%2F*%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fgapi%2F_*features*_%2Frt%3Dj%2Fver%3DlgJnpFHo_sE.es.%2Fsv%3D1%2Fam%3D!9YrXPIrxx2-ITyEIjA%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTMUGsaYaMyYb_qFDQo8MG8RKB82aQ#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Conload&id=I1_1352910400423&parent=file%3A%2F%2F

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot thus far?

Comment: not how to fix it, I work in Safari, the problem is with other browsers

Comment: From [https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/], did you include both pieces? We also have video instructions for how to add the badge. [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLG4IIIPgnc]

If you followed these steps, can you provide any information on the debugging you have done thusfar?

Comment: Are you saying that the badge doesn't render? 

Or are you saying that in the circle chooser, that when you try to use the create new circle option that doesn't work and you then see an error?

You should also always include the code that you're attempting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are testing this code locally served through the `file://` protocol as shown in the query parameter:

```
origin=file%3A%2F%2F&url=file%3A%2F%2F%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fusuario%2FDesktop%2Fnoche.html
```

Place your file in a location that can be served through http. Upload the page to your site or install a web server to test on.

I believe I was able to duplicate what you saw in Chrome and Safari; however, this approach is not a supported method to use the plugin and wouldn't be used to serve the page to real users.